# Restricting Tika LanguageIdentifier to specific languages only

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I am trying to restrict the Apache Tika LanguageIdentifier to an array of languages. When i run my code below, it only detects texts as "de", hence german. The reason i want to do this is to let the LanguageIdentifier perform better due to language restriction. After cleaning the standard profiles, i only add the profiles i want to a map and initialize the LanguageIdentifier with this map.

```
String[] languages = {"de", "en", "fr", "nl", "es"};
Map<String, LanguageProfile> languageMaps = new HashMap <String, LanguageProfile>();

LanguageIdentifier.clearProfiles();

        for (String language : languages) {

    LanguageProfile profile = new LanguageProfile();
    languageMaps.put(language, profile);

    }

    LanguageIdentifier.initProfiles(languageMaps);

String docText = "Hello";


LanguageIdentifier identifier = new LanguageIdentifier(docText);

System.out.println(identifier.getLanguage());
```

When I run the following code

```
LanguageIdentifierLanguageIdentifier.getSupportedLanguages())
```

It returns the languages from the array, so I don't really know what is wrong.

Comment: What happens if you try with a sensible lengthed text string? Language detection really needs a fair bit of text to be able to make a sensible guess

Comment: Yes, i know. The code above is just an example. In fact I read a lot of texts and ALL are classified as german..

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `LanguageProfile` you have to add all the ngram information for the defined language on your own again. With this setup you just create empty containers and therfor always choose the first in the array because its the first and you don't have any other information.

See [API documentation of LanguageProfile](https://tika.apache.org/1.11/api/org/apache/tika/language/LanguageProfile.html#add%28java.lang.String,%20long%29)

Just take the nedded language ngram files from
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/language/

Initialize it with (Supposing the ngram files are in your classpath root):

```
String[] languages = { "de", "en" };

Map<String, LanguageProfile> languageMaps = new HashMap<String, LanguageProfile>();

LanguageIdentifier.clearProfiles();

for (String language : languages) {

    LanguageProfile profile = new LanguageProfile();

    InputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File("./" + language + ".ngp"));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, UTF_8));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            if (line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith("#")) {
                int space = line.indexOf(' ');
                profile.add(line.substring(0, space), Long.parseLong(line.substring(space + 1)));
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    languageMaps.put(language, profile);

}

LanguageIdentifier.initProfiles(languageMaps);
```